# Fill PDFP Table Cell with Dots

Tags: c#, itext

I have a PDFP Table and I want to have it laid out like so:

```
Item1 ............  $10.00
Item1123123 ......  $50.00
Item3 ............  $75.00
```

This is what I have so far:

```
var tableFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 7);
var items = from p in ctx.quote_server_totals
            where p.item_id == id
               && p.name != "total"
               && p.type != "totals"
            select p;

foreach (var innerItem in items)
{               
    detailsTable.AddCell(new Phrase(innerItem.type == "discount" ? "ADJUSTMENT -" + innerItem.name : innerItem.name, tableFont));
    detailsTable.AddCell(new Phrase(".......................................................", tableFont));
    detailsTable.AddCell(new Phrase(Convert.ToDecimal(innerItem.value).ToString("c"), tableFont));
}
document.Add(detailsTable);
```

As can see, the only way I've been able to get the dots to extend is by manually entering them; however, this obviously won't work because the the first column's width will be different every time I run this code. Is there a way I can accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Pick a total width (Item name + $xx.xx + padding).  Subtract the item name and the padding and the total. Print that many dots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please download [chapter 2 of my book](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter2.pdf) and search for `DottedLineSeparator`. This separator class will draw a dotted line between two parts of a `Paragraph` (as shown in the figures in the book). You can find the C# version of the Java book samples [here](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C02).

Comment: Ahh; sir, you are a gentleman and a scholar... I tip my hat to you. May your days be full of warmth and endless bounty!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a fixed-width font such as `FontFactory.COURIER` your task will be a lot easier.

```
//Our main font
var tableFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 20);

//Will hold the shortname from the database
string itemShortName;

//Will hold the long name which includes the periods
string itemNameFull;

//Maximum number of characters that will fit into the cell
int maxLineLength = 23;

//Our table
var t = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 75, 25 });

for (var i = 1; i < 10000; i+=100) {
    //Get our item name from "the database"
    itemShortName = "Item " + i.ToString();

    //Add dots based on the length
    itemNameFull = itemShortName + ' ' + new String('.', maxLineLength - itemShortName.Length + 1);

    //Add the two cells
    t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(itemNameFull, tableFont)) { Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER });
    t.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(25.ToString("c"), tableFont)) { Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER });
}
```